# Is it possible to revoke Mfa sessions from graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

I would like to revoke existing mfa sessions of my users.

In portal, I can do this by selecting this option

[image]

But I want to do this from graph. Is this possible?

I tried finding the related query and got this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/id/revokeSignInSessions
```

Is this the same as Revoke multifactor authentication sessions option?

Can someone suggest if I'm missing any Or help me with right query?

Comment: I'm dealing with the same challange and filed a feature request to Microsoft. If anybody likes to support this, you're invited to vote for it https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/f9721c7f-a759-ee11-a81c-000d3ae46fcb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is not possible to revoke MFA sessions using Microsoft Graph**. The `/revokeSignInSessions` operation invalidates refresh tokens and session cookies while Revoke MFA sessions does exactly that :)